# How to enable full screen Pan back for UINavigationController

Tags: ios, gesture, uipangesturerecognizer

From iOS7 apple provide a way to pan back UINavigationController, but it can only be done by swipe form the edge of the screen. How to enable full screen pan back gesture?

Comment: you can use `Screen Edge Pan Gesture Recognizer` from `object directory` also to acheive this..!!

Comment: @Sneha  You can only swipe  from the edge with ScreenEdgePanGesture, how to deal with if you want to pan from the middle?

Comment: sorry i misunderstand, you can use simple `Swipe Gesture Recognizer` for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really spend a lot of time trying to solve this problem, at last I found the way. I just ask a question and answer it myself to share the solution here.

Pls refer my blog to get more detail [enter link description here](http://liudanyun.com/blog/?p=452)

Demo code:

```
#import "TestNavigationController.h"

@interface _UINavigationInteractiveTransition

@end

@interface UINavigationController(Custom)
@property (strong, nonatomic) _UINavigationInteractiveTransition * _cachedInteractionController;

@end

@implementation TestNavigationController
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *_p;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer
          );
    _p = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self._cachedInteractionController action:@selector(handleNavigationTransition:)];
    NSLog(@"%@", self._cachedInteractionController);
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_p];
   } 
@end
```

**EDIT NOTE:**
This exposes Private APIs.

Comment: I think this exposes private APIs